# Capture print date and hide report

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am displaying a crystal report that displays record for particular user.

Requirement is like
1. If Print of that report is taken out, then that user should not be visible that for 1 month (30 days to be precise). Hence if i print the report on Jan 1 2011 for user John Smith, that record for John Smith should not appear till Jan 30 2011, On Jan 31, that record should again come up in report.

I'm using

1. Visual Studio 2005 (C#)
2. Crystal Report (Crystal Report viewer to view reports)

My Query:

1. How to capture print date?
2. How should i proceed to fulfill my requirement?

Please guide me esp in the Logic department :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going by when the user prints the report from the `CrystalReportViewer` you could try adding a last printed date field to your data source, then trigger an update when the report gets printed by overriding the `CrystalReportViewer` class eg::

```
class MyViewer : CrystalReportViewer
{
    public override void PrintReport()
    {
        base.PrintReport();
        /* Update your datasource to set last printed date = now */
    }
}
```